# EF: The property 'Street' is not a declared property on type 'Address'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm getting the following error when I try to get all the `Suppliers` with Entity Framework 6.1.

> The property 'Street' is not a declared property on type 'Address'.
>   Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the
>   model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

My entities look like this:

Supplier.cs:

```
public class Supplier : AggregateRoot
{
    // public int Id: defined in AggregateRoot class

    public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; private set; }

    protected Supplier() { }

    public Supplier(string companyName)
    {
        CompanyName = companyName;
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    public void ChangeCompanyName(string newCompanyName)
    {
        CompanyName = newCompanyName;
    }
}
```

Address.cs:

```
public class Address : ValueObject<Address>
{
    // public int Id: defined in ValueObject class

    public string Street { get; }
    public string Number { get; }
    public string Zipcode { get; }

    protected Address() { }

    protected override bool EqualsCore(Address other)
    {
        // removed for sake of simplicity
    }

    protected override int GetHashCodeCore()
    {
        // removed for sake of simplicity
    }
}
```

I also have two mappings defined:

SupplierMap.cs

```
public class SupplierMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
{
    public SupplierMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyName).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

AddressMap.cs

```
public class AddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Street).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        this.Property(t => t.Number).IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.Zipcode).IsOptional();
    }
}
```

But when I run the following code I gives me the error described above:

```
using (var ctx = new DDDv1Context())
{
    var aaa = ctx.Suppliers.First(); // Error here...
}
```

The code works when I remove the `ICollection` from the `Supplier.cs` class and also remove the mapping class from my db context:

```
public class DDDv1Context : DbContext
{
    static DDDv1Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DDDv1Context>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; } //Can leave this without problems

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SupplierMap());

        // Now code works when trying to get supplier
        //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressMap());
    }

}
```

Why does the code give an error when I try to use it with the `Address` class and `AddresMap` class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Street property is immutable, it has to have a setter for your code to work. Currently, you don't have a setter defined on Street and that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. However, the `Address` class is a `ValueObject` and should be immutable. To solve this issue I added a `protected set` to each property instead of a public one. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: A `private set;` would also work here, but be warned that ReSharper etc would probably warn that "Auto-property can be made readonly" (because it appears to be functionally redundant).